# Is a DDR3 MB compatible with DDR2 RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility, ddr3, ddr2

If a motherboard's specifications say it supports DDR3 SDRAM sticks, would I be correct to assume it is also compatible with DDR2 RAM? Am I wrong, or does it depend on the motherboard?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. DDR3 and DDR2 are designed differently. Both have different key placing so they won't even physically fit, not to mention differences in electrical voltage:

[image]

There are motherboards which will provide **entirely separate** slots for DDR2, but you cannot use DDR3 in DDR2 slots, or both types together.

Comment: dang it, beat me to it by a minute!

Answer (score 6):

> Supports DDR3 SDRAM sticks, would I be
>   correct to assume it is also
>   compatible with DDR2 RAM?

That's incorrect. DDR3 Rams are [PIN & voltage incompatible](http://www.anandtech.com/memory/showdoc.aspx?i=2989&p=2).

> Or does it depend on the motherboard?

[Certain motherboards](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/MSi-Eight-Memory-Slots,7214.html) provide DDR2 & DDR3 slots, but you can use only 1 type at a time, you cannot mix and match both